# Completely delete confidential files and folders

Tags: centos, safe-remove

I'm going to switch to a new VPS and I want to completely delete some confidential files/folders from the current VPS (and MySQL content too). The server is running CENTOS 6.

Btw, it's **not** `rm -rf`. I want to remove files/folders without recovery (that means erase all inode contents, not just unlink them).

Is there tool to do so?

Comment: I've found out that wipe (http://wipe.sourceforge.net/) may be the best way for safe deletion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take a look at `shred`, which overwrites files repeatedly, making recovery a lot harder.

Comment: Make sure to also shred tempfs.